# Java Robot, finding certain images on screen

Tags: java, pixel, awtrobot

I am trying to use the Java Robot class to create a bot to automate some tedious tasks for me, I have never used the Robot class. I have looked up the Class in the Java docs, usage seems straightforward but I have an issue of finding a certain image(I say image, I mean a certain part of the screen) effectively. Is there any other way other than loading 'x' ammount of pixels, checking them, checking the next ammount etc until I find the image I am looking for? Also is there any list of the Button and MouseButton identifiers needed for the Java Robot class as I cna not find any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the mouse button identifiers, you are supposed to use BUTTON1_MASK and other button mask constants from java.awt.event.MouseEvent. For example, to click the mouse you would do something like:

```
Robot r = new Robot();
r.mousePress(MouseEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
r.mouseRelease(MouseEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
```

I believe BUTTON1_MASK is the left mouse button, BUTTON2_MASK is the middle mouse button, and BUTTON3_MASK is the right mouse button, but it has been a month or so since I have used Robot.

As for the checking for an image, I have no idea how that is normally done. But the way you specified in your question where you just check every group of pixels shouldn't be too computationally expensive because you can get the screen image as an array of primitives, then just access the desired pixel with a bit of math. So when checking the "rectangle" of pixels that you are searching for your image in, only keep checking the pixels as long as the pixels keep matching. The moment you find a pixel that does not match, move onto the next "rectangle" of pixels. The probability that you will find a bunch of pixels that match the image that end up not being the image is extremely low, meaning that each rectangle will only need to check about 5 or fewer pixels on average. Any software that performs this task would have to check every pixel on the screen at least once (unless it makes a few shortcuts/assumptions based on probabilities of image variations occurring), and the algorithm I described would check each pixel about 5 times, so it is not that bad to implement, unless you have a huge image to check.

Hope this helps!